# when user click on button/cardview then they will see ad after showing ad i wanna do something like Toast or other

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

i want to add something like this in android studio
**when user click on button/cardview then they will see ad after showing ad i wanna do something like Toast or other**

here is my java code

```
adbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

//before that i want to show ad and after showing ad i want to do this
                int i = Integer.parseInt(pointstext.getText().toString());
                pointstext.setText(String.valueOf(i + 150));
            }
        });
```

and XML

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="000000"
    android:id="@+id/points"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Load an ad

---

To load an interstitial ad, call the `InterstitialAd` static [load()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView#loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)) method and pass in an InterstitialAdLoadCallback to receive the loaded ad or any possible errors. Notice that like other format load callbacks, InterstitialAdLoadCallback leverages LoadAdError to provide higher fidelity error details.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
      });
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

      InterstitialAd.load(this,"your-google-ad-key", adRequest,
        new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
        // an ad is loaded.
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
        // Handle the error
        Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
        mInterstitialAd = null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

### Show the ad

---

In the `onClick` method of the button add this:

```
adbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show(MyActivity.this);
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
                }
            }
        });
```

### Know when ad finished

---

Add this code:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        //AdClosed now reward user with points etc
        int i = Integer.parseInt(pointstext.getText().toString());
        pointstext.setText(String.valueOf(i + 150));
    }
});
```

Comment: i know that, but i want to show this ad when user click on a Button, and when this ad closed i want to add [ int i = Integer.parseInt(pointstext.getText().toString());
                pointstext.setText(String.valueOf(i + 150));  ] aqtually when user click on button i wanna show ad and after showing ad some points will be add on pointstext (TextView).  can i do this, if i do then how ? please give me solution anytype . iam using android studio latest version , Advance thanks

Comment: I have added a method called `onAdClosed`. check the code. There you can add this code. It will work

Comment: and call `displayInderstitial();` inside the click of a button

Comment: I have edited the answer. please check it

Comment: Thank You Dear Brother :)

Comment: ok,, iam going to test this,  after test i will give tick mark,, just a minute please

Comment: iam facing some problem please see the image [link](https://paste.pics/FV49U) _italic_ **bold** in app  ` implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'`

Comment: did you import the class ?

Comment: yes, i also pres ALT+ENTER it show me rename

Comment: can you send the image of what all options it shows?

Comment: yeah sure... [here](https://paste.pics/FV4C7)

Comment: click ALT+ENTER on `new InderstitialAd` thing and send the image

Comment: hold on! Is the activity name `MainActivity`?

Comment: iam doing thats on MainActivity. here is the image , it show me to do implements  new method please see [link](https://paste.pics/FV4G3)

Comment: yes. click it and it will work

Comment: please see this image [link](https://paste.pics/FV4II)

Comment: refer to this class -> https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/java/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/interstitialexample/MyActivity.java

Comment: or wait. I will edit the answer

Comment: it works, but , i want to add some code, like- if mInterstitialAd is succesfully show then i want to add some number on my pointstext(TEXTVIEW) , how can i do ? can you create this ?